# How to pass parameters to mainLayoutAsset.php file?

Tags: yii2

I have following code in mainLayoutAsset.php file

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace frontend\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class MainLayoutAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
    ];
    public $js = [
        'member-area/AdminLTE/app.js',
    ];
}
```

Now I want to access params file parameter in to this file

eg.

```
public $js = [
        'member-area/AdminLTE/app.js?v='.Yii::$app->params["version"],
     ]
```

but it giving error

```
PHP Parse Error – yii\base\ErrorException
syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']'

'js/tooltip.js?v='.Yii::$app->params["incFileVersion"],
```

Comment: `expression is not allowed as field default value` ... Why don't you use `appendTimestamp` of `AssetManager` class

Comment: I don't want to use timestamp as it will change value everytime. What I want is whenever I change my JS files. I just need to change the version so that the new jquery is included and not the cached one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From PHP documentation about class properties :

> They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

You could simply override `init()` :

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    $this->js = [
        'member-area/AdminLTE/app.js?v=' . Yii::$app->params['version'],
    ];
}
```

And you should may be [try this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#cache-busting) instead.